# MySQL Error 1451

Tags: mysql

Command:

```
DELETE FROM  `meetings`.`meetingparticipants` WHERE  `meetingparticipants`.`idParticipants` =503 AND  `meetingparticipants`.`idMeetings` =83
```

I know I have a simple error in my database.  I am attempting to delete a row from the meeting participants table and receiving the following error:

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`meetings`.`invoices`, CONSTRAINT `fk_meetingid` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_meetingid`) REFERENCES `meetingparticipants` (`idMeetings`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Any ideas?  I think I need a foreign key relationship between the participant table and the meeting-participant table with updates, but I rather confirm or see if there are any suggestions??

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoices` (
  `idinvoices` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_invoiceType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DocNum` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DZ` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_meetingid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_participantid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoiceNotes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoiceDocuments` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idinvoices`),
  UNIQUE KEY `DOC_Num` (`DocNum`),
  KEY `fk_invoiceType` (`fk_invoiceType`),
  KEY `fk_meetingid` (`fk_meetingid`),
  KEY `fk_participantid` (`fk_participantid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1014 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `invoicestatus`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoicestatus` (
  `idinvoiceStatus` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoiceStatus` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idinvoiceStatus`),
  UNIQUE KEY `invoiceStatus_UNIQUE` (`invoiceStatus`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `invoicestatushistory`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoicestatushistory` (
  `fk_invoiceStatus` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `statusStamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_idinvoices` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idinvoiceStatusHistory` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idinvoiceStatusHistory`,`fk_idinvoices`),
  KEY `invoiceStatusHistory` (`fk_invoiceStatus`),
  KEY `invoiceid` (`fk_idinvoices`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1015 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `invoicetypes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoicetypes` (
  `idinvoiceTypes` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoiceType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idinvoiceTypes`),
  UNIQUE KEY `invoiceType_UNIQUE` (`invoiceType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `meetingparticipants`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `meetingparticipants` (
  `idParticipants` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idMeetings` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invited` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attended` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `travelCostsReimbursed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ParticipantFeeEligible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ParticipantFeeProcessed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idParticipants`,`idMeetings`),
  KEY `idParticipants` (`idParticipants`),
  KEY `idMeetings` (`idMeetings`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `meetings`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `meetings` (
  `idmeetings` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `meetingName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `beginDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `endDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meetingNotes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meetingDocuments` blob,
  `fk_programID` int(110) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmeetings`),
  UNIQUE KEY `meetingName_UNIQUE` (`meetingName`),
  KEY `programid` (`fk_programID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=85 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `participants`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `participants` (
  `idparticipants` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `preferredName` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `affiliation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `foreignNational` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grantPaid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bannerid` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `participantNotes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `participantDocuments` blob,
  `visaType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idparticipants`),
  UNIQUE KEY `bannerid_UNIQUE` (`bannerid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=507 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `programs`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `programs` (
  `idprograms` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProgramName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idprograms`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ProgramName_UNIQUE` (`ProgramName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `userPassword` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'password',
  `userLevel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userName` (`userName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `visatypes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visatypes` (
  `idvisaTypes` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `visaType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paymentInstructions` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idvisaTypes`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `invoices`
--
ALTER TABLE `invoices`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_invoiceType` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_invoiceType`) REFERENCES `invoicetypes` (`idinvoiceTypes`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_meetingid` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_meetingid`) REFERENCES `meetingparticipants` (`idMeetings`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_participantid` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_participantid`) REFERENCES `meetingparticipants` (`idParticipants`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Constraints for table `invoicestatushistory`
--
ALTER TABLE `invoicestatushistory`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `invoiceid` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_idinvoices`) REFERENCES `invoices` (`idinvoices`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `invoiceStatusHistory` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_invoiceStatus`) REFERENCES `invoicestatus` (`idinvoiceStatus`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `meetings`
--
ALTER TABLE `meetings`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `programid` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_programID`) REFERENCES `programs` (`idprograms`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key constraint on the `invoices` table that is named "fk_meetingid", but references the `meetingparticipants` table, which is an association table. It would seem to me that if an invoice were linked to a meeting that it should be linked directly to the `meetings` table.

Comment: What I have is a table of participants, a table of meetings, and a table of invoices.  Since, a participant may go to one or more meetings and a meeting may have one or more participants there is the intersection table of meeting-participants.  Each participant may be issued one or more invoices, too.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

> NO ACTION: A keyword from standard SQL. In MySQL, equivalent to
>   RESTRICT. InnoDB rejects the delete or update operation for the parent
>   table if there is a related foreign key value in the referenced table.
>   Some database systems have deferred checks, and NO ACTION is a
>   deferred check. In MySQL, foreign key constraints are checked
>   immediately, so NO ACTION is the same as RESTRICT.

If I understand your schema, (which is unlikely after looking at it for 30 seconds), you probably want to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` so that a participants invoices are deleted when you delete the participant. If you need to keep the invoices but delete the participant then choose `ON DELETE SET NULL`

Comment: Thank you...I think that is actually the issue, I'll hunt in the invoices table for an invoice that is linked to that participate, delete manually, and try your idea -- I believe it solves it...